# Update email field regex value in WFFM Sitecore 8

Tags: regex, webforms, sitecore

I am trying to update regx value for Email field in below two place but still when email field renders ,it showing regx "^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+.[A-Za-z]{2,17}$", not able to find from where does it render the given Regx.

1. /sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Field Types/Simple Types/E-mail
2. /sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Validation/E-mail

Comment: Do you have `EmailValidation` setting somewhere in your `App_Config` folder? You can check it using `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` page

Comment: Yes there is , but its different value="^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$"

Answer (score 0):

Try to set it in the `Parameters` field of your email-field-item. I think you should use `<EmailRegularExpression>...</EmailRegularExpression>` - not tested though.
The regex that you see is the default value set in the code.